# PrefererenceFragment Material Theme with Support Library

Tags: android, themes, android-appcompat, preferencefragment

I've adopted the Material design in my app using appcompat v22. Everything worked well and the theme is applied, but the PreferenceFragments still look like the native Android's theme and not like Material.

As I'm forced to support all the way down to API level 10 I use [this backport](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment).

Is there any way to make the PreferenceFragment apply the AppCompat theme?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you would have to use AppCompat toolbar + PreferenceActivity: https://xisberto.wordpress.com/2014/11/08/how-to-combine-actionbar-and-preferenceactivity-headers-with-appcompat/

Answer (score 0):

With the new 22.1+ appcompat you can use the [AppCompatDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html) to extend AppCompat's support to any Activity.

You can check this official link to [AppCompatPreferenceActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java), where you can find an example of this technique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I copied the linked AppCompatPreferenceActivity into my project and used it instead of the PreferenceFragments, but it still did not apply the AppCompat theme